# Unable to add build step in jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

I was able to create the new job but I am NOT able to add any build step.
This behaviour is reproducible and it occurs when I try to do it from the initial “configure” page I get after job creation  as well as with a later configure attempt. And its persists for all job types.
 It does not depend on whether I am logged in or not.
 The problem is that when I open the “add build step” I get a selection of possible job types (“shell script”, “windows batch”, …) but when I select one of those nothing more happens.
 I also have other jobs of this type already up and running and I am also not able to add more build steps to those.

Comment: Maybe Jenkins->Manage Jenkins->system log ->All jenkins logs can throw some light on the root cause.

Comment: Do you have enough free disk space?

Comment: Now I am able to add it. 
On Jenkins- Configuration- Jenkins Location, I had put https instead of http, I guess that was the reason. I reverted back to http and its working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this with v1.625.3, all of a sudden. Problem in Chrome and FF. Workaround was to use IE.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue in IE on Windows 7